# Se duplica el Activity al abrir desde notificacion

Tags: android

tengo un problema, al abrir la activity desde una notificación esta se me duplica y obviamente consulta a mis API´s nuevamente

Me pueden ayudar con esto? quiero abrir la activity pero que no se duplique ni que vuelva a cargar los datos.

Se puede? dejo el método que tengo para la notificación

Gracias

```
public void notificacion(String Mensaje) {
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SecondActivity.this, null);
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                CharSequence name = "Notificacion";

                String description = "Comunicaión a usuarios";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, name, importance);

                channel.setDescription(description);
                channel.enableLights(true);

                channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
                channel.enableVibration(true);
                channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SecondActivity.this, channelID);
    }

    notificacion.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_chat)
            .setContentTitle("Notificacion")
            .setContentText(Mensaje)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificacion.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
    manager.notify(id, notificacion.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente toma en cuenta :

Cuando crees la notificación recuerda definir el [ChannelID](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels) y además el contexto debe ser el de la Activity que genera la Notificación y no la Activity que se abriría al dar clic en la notificación

```
//notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SecondActivity.this, null);
notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SecondActivity.this, channelID);
```

Además estas creando nuevamente otra instancia de  NotificationCompat.Builder :

```
notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SecondActivity.this, null);
...
...
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
  ...
  ...
   notificacion = new NotificationCompat.Builder(SecondActivity.this, channelID);

}
```

---

Causa por las cual generas nuevamente la notificación:

Si se esta creando nuevamente la notificación, es debido a que defines a tu `PendingIntent` un `Intent` el cual indica abrir nuevamente `SecondActivity` y esta clase esta generando la notificación:

```
  Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**si deseas que no se duplique la Activity define para esta en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` la propiedad `android:launchMode="singleTask"` :**

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

> [android:launchMode="singleTask"](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=es-419#lmode) : Una `Activity` con `launchMode`
>   definido como `singleTask` solo puede tener una instancia en el
>   sistema (similar a un Singleton).

---